# Angular application Signin Redirect fails with "invalid_grant" error when running on different machine than the IDP

Tags: angular, typescript, identityserver4, oidc-client

I am using oidc-client with Angular to log in to my identity server. When running both applications on the same machine everything works perfectly.

However when I run my Identity Server on a Web Apps server and my Angular Application on a Static Web App I get an error "invalid_grant".

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

1. User clicks on Login button and gets redirected to the login screen of Identity Server
2. User enters Password and Username and clicks Log In
3. Identity Server redirects to the "signin-callback" link and I get the blank signin-callback page because signin callback is only a .ts script

   This URL appears in the header: https://white-wave-0ca3e8803.azurestaticapps.net/signin-callback?code=l5-p3B5IGifAZ3ijIUgKmLl7aL2g45Fh5JLmluOj3NA&scope=openid%20profile&state=6503e1f5f176411a890ac50a4d0ecb84&session_state=aPnjQ5ZUiMCDKkAztm0O0K4quSkfSlWRZd--YuK73Oc.NVxBA5K6RH5_ptpDobxmxA

   Under network we have a red "Token" error.
   Containing **Response Header**
   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
   Pragma: no-cache
   Content-Length: 25
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://white-wave-0ca3e8803.azurestaticapps.net/dashboard
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=1fa22e5e18dd42b9d22d6c2c620b562f117da68736f4d32b741538a2d054d95c;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=hansecoreidp-staging.azurewebsites.net
   Set-Cookie: ARRAffinitySameSite=1fa22e5e18dd42b9d22d6c2c620b562f117da68736f4d32b741538a2d054d95c;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=hansecoreidp-staging.azurewebsites.net
   Date: Thu, 18 Mar 2021 08:34:39 GMT

   **Error Message**
   {"error":"invalid_grant"}
4. When I refresh I get the error *Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No matching state found in storage* the local storage, session storage and cookies are empty.
5. When I delete the everything after my base URL https://white-wave-0ca3e8803.azurestaticapps.net, navigate to the base url and click login again, **the login works** and in the storage I all of a sudden have
   **Cookie Storage** A cookie containing AAR Affinity, etc from Identity server
   **Session Storage** I have the *access_token, id_token, profile, scope, etc.*
   **Local Storage** *Authority, client_id, etc.*

**ASSUMPTION**
I think the Angular application is having trouble storing the information from the signin-callback in the *application storage*.

**IDENTITY SERVER CONFIGURATION CODE**

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> StagingClients (IConfiguration configuration) =>
        new Client[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "HAnsecore.Web",
                ClientId = "clientid",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                RedirectUris = new List<string>{ "https://white-wave-0ca3e8803.azurestaticapps.net/signin-callback" },
                RequirePkce = true,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "hansecoreCQRSApi",
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://white-wave-0ca3e8803.azurestaticapps.net" },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "https://white-wave-0ca3e8803.azurestaticapps.net/signout-callback" },
                RequireConsent = false,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 600
            }
        };
```

**ANGULAR OIDC-CLIENT AUTH CONFIG CODE**

```
private get idpSettings() : UserManagerSettings {
return {
  authority: environment.idpAuthority,
  client_id: environment.clientId,
  redirect_uri: `${environment.clientRoot}/signin-callback`,
  scope: "openid profile hansecoreCQRSApi offline_access",
  response_type: "code",

  post_logout_redirect_uri: `${environment.clientRoot}/signout-callback`
}
```

}

**SIGNIN REDIRECT CALLBACK CODE**
User Manager is an inherited class from *oidc-client*. When debugging the code does not enter the .then and I can't debug any further than here. But I think whatever happens after this is where the code fails.

```
public finishLogin = (): Promise<User> => {
return this._userManager.signinRedirectCallback()
.then(user => {
  this._loginChangedSubject.next(this.checkUser(user));
  return user;
})
```

}

**SIGNIN CALLBACK CODE**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../../core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin-redirect-callback',
  template: `<div></div>`
})
export class SigninRedirectCallbackComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private _router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._authService.finishLogin()
    .then(_ => {
      this._router.navigate(['/'], { replaceUrl: true });
    })
  }

}
```

**NETWORK PICTURE**
[image: Network traffic on fail]

If theres anything missing in my question at all please let me know.

**EVNIRONMENT FILE**

```
export const environment = {
  environmentName: 'STAGE',
  production: false,
  apiRoot: 'https://hansecoreapi-staging.azurewebsites.net/api/',
  clientRoot: 'https://white-wave-0ca3e8803.azurestaticapps.net',
  idpAuthority: 'https://hansecoreidp-staging.azurewebsites.net',
  clientId: '54212148-15C1-40F9-BA07-E3CE748A7C7F'
};
```

Comment: Are you using HTTP somewhere in the deployment? or HTTPS all the way? some cookies might be ignored over HTTP

Comment: I Added the environment file. Is there anywhere else I should look?